# GSP pass Array from controller and display in gsp by its index

Tags: grails, gsp

how can I pass an array from controller to gsp, and view it by index in that gsp?

Lets say in controller:

```
String[] str= new String[2];
str[0]="A"
str[1]="B"

render(view: "test_preview",model:[flag:str])
```

and in gsp, how can i call let say index [1] value "B" specifically in the gsp without any looping possibly?

Comment: what is *index* ?
did you try *${flag[1]}* in your gsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

1. You pass full array to view. And in your view, you do the following:

   ```
   ${flag[1]}
   ```
2. Or: you only pass the specific value to view. In your controller:

   ```
   render(view: "test_preview",model:[flag:str[1])
   ```

   And in your view:

   ```
   ${flag}
   ```